# No Products Populate in Pricebook to add to Opp

Tags: pricebook, product

There is so much info online about this already and I have already checked off the following which I am told would be causing an empty product list when trying to add products to my opp in the UI.  Am i missing something? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

- Custom Pricebook exists and is active
- Custom Pricebook is assigned to the specific Opportunity
- Pricebook Entries exists for the Custom Pricebook and is active
- Product is active
- NOT multi currency and is set to USD.

Comment: And the user in question has Use access to the price book?

Answer (score -1):

Plese check all these points.

- Product is active
- Product has Standard Price
- Product should be add in your Custom Pricebook
- Custom Pricebook exists and is active
- Custom Pricebook is assigned to the specific Opportunity.

Regards,
Akshay

Comment: Yes both my product and pricebook are active.  My opportunity is set to the pricebook. My product has an amount. I dont have multi currency on and its set to USD.  The problem is when I try to add products to my opp the pricebook list is empty.